# OFBiz-11.04 deployment in JBoss-5.1.0

Tags: jboss5.x, ofbiz

In order to get flexibility in load balancing and clustering, I thought of deploying my OFBiz application in JBoss-5.1.0 as per document (https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBTECH/deploying-ofbiz-904-on-jboss-510.html).

Build was successful and I could see all WAR files in server/default/deploy/OFBiz.ear and other JAR files in lib folder. But I am getting a few issues when starting JBoss server. Please take a look and help me if you have any clues.

### Issues:

1. Could not find definition for entity name EntityKeyStore 
   ...................... 
   Could not find definition for entity name JobSandbox 
   ...................

   Entity definitions for EntityKeyStore is located in entitymodel.xml of framework/entity/entitydef folder. I could not find this xml anywhere inside OFBiz.ear.  (Not only this XML, none of the entitymodel.xml s are found in ear. But no issue with other entities. I do not know why it is so). I checked my database (server/default/data/derby) and found out ENTITY_KEY_STORE there.

The same is the case for JobSandBox.

1. After this exception, the server seems to proceed with creating dispatcher for each component and it started with accounting. I am getting another issue here.

Could not get root location for component with name [common], error was: org.ofbiz.base.component.ComponentException: No component found named : common 
..... 
.... 
.... 
---- exception report ---------------------------------------------------------- 
Error processing include at [component://common/webcommon/WEB-INF/common-controller.xml]:java.net.MalformedURLException: Could not get root location for component with name [common], error was: org.ofbiz.base.component.ComponentException: No component found named : common 
Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException

This exception is repeatedly printed in log file. And down the line, the same kind of exception is thrown for other components like commonext, accounting and ecommerce.

After these exceptions "Could not find definition for entity name Tenant" is also thrown.

My OFBiz application uses a multitenant environment. Any help is greatly appreciated.